# css style for a button does not work

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have an extremely trivial case. I have a button and I want to add an icon to this button. The file structure of the project looks like this:

```
testpackage/
    - Test.java
    - add.gif
    - my.css
```

So, this code works relatively fine:

```
Button b1 = new Button();        
b1.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/testpackage/add.gif');" +
            "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;" +
            "-fx-background-position: center;");
```

But I do not want to hardcode css style, instead I want to use `my.css`. This file - `my.css` - looks like:

```
.add-button {
  -fx-background-image: url('/testpackage/add.gif');
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -fx-background-position: center;
}
```

However, when I try to use it like so

```
 Button b1 = new Button();        
 b1.getStyleClass().add("add-button");
```

it does not work. Thanks fro help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the stylesheet to your scene first:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400);
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/stylesheet.css");
```

Then you can assign classes, like you did above.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the style sheet as well .

```
b1.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("my.css").toExternalForm();
b1.getStyleClass().add("add-button");
```